# Implementing Decrease Key with STL heap in O(logn) time

Tags: c++, stl, heap

At the moment STL Heap does not support decrease key, however one can just change the value on the vector directly and call make_heap again which is O(n) time.  However that's not as efficient as a binary heap decrease key which would take O(logn) time.

Is there a way to achieve O(logn) time using STL heap functions?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure there's no standard-conforming way of doing it - [Wikipedia says so too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29):

> there is no standard support for the decrease/increase-key operation

Although it does go on to point to the `gheap` library, which might well be worth a look.

The problem here is that the standard does not mandate what form the heap structure takes, nor how exactly the operations are performed. (In general this is a good thing.)

If the implementation is using a standard binary heap then I think you can simply decrease the element at `heap[i]` and then call `push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.begin() + i + 1)`, which will do the necessary up-heap operation. The element that ends up at position `i` must have been no larger than the value there originally, and so the heap property of the whole heap is preserved. But this is not supported by the standard even if it does work sometimes in some implementations.

Comment: And what about an increase_key operation? Can you do it using the operations over the heap in the std? (Assume I'm using binary heap over a vector)

Comment: @Gonzalo That seems like it should be a new question.

Comment: How do you find the correct `i`, ie the heap-position of the actual entity whose key is supposed to be decreased?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pop_heap` followed by decrementing the value followed by `push_heap`:

```
int main() {
    //Create the heap
    std::vector<int> heap{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    std::make_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());

    //Decrease key
    std::pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
    --*(std::prev(heap.end()));
    std::push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
}
```

EDIT: Is this what you mean, or do you want to be able to decrease the key of *any* element in the heap?